# Generate points along geometry and avoid polylines

Tags: qgis, point, geometry

I am trying to generate preliminary sign poles location with the QGIS function *points along geometry*. I was able to generate points in respect of distance requirements. I would like to know if there is a way to add a condition to avoid polygons in other layers while generating those points.

Comment: There's a way, but it would probably involve modeling to split/remove the segments along where you don't want signs.

Comment: If there is a polygon covering parts of a line, do you want to start over the distance measuring after the polygon or continue the measuring from before the polygon?

Comment: I don't want to start over the distance everytime there's a polygon. Hence, I can't cut the polylines where it intersects the polygons. I am looking for a way to exclude those areas when the algorithm generates those points.

Answer (score 1):

Create the points, then make the differnce of these points with the intersection polygons, e.g. with Geometry by Expression or Geometry Generator:

```
difference (
    collect_geometries(
        array_foreach(
            generate_series(1,50),
            line_interpolate_point( 
                $geometry, 
                @element*0.08
            )
        )
    ),
    collect_geometries(
        overlay_intersects(
            'polygon',
            $geometry
        )
    )
)
```

[image]